# Finding 1st transaction date in SAS

Tags: sas, ssas

I have 2 customers 2 months transaction date, now i need to extract only 1st transaction date for that month for that particular customer. Like that i need month wise. I didn't get proper idea on this on SAS. Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance.

`Cust_name  Vis_date
V   3/1/2016
V   8/1/2016
V   16/1/2016
V   18/1/2016
V   26/1/2016
V   27/1/2016
E   5/1/2016
E   8/1/2016
E   18/1/2016
E   19/1/2016
E   25/1/2016
E   26/1/2016
V   4/2/2016
V   8/2/2016
V   17/2/2016
V   25/2/2016
V   26/2/2016
V   27/2/2016
E   5/2/2016
E   8/2/2016
E   23/2/2016
E   24/2/2016
E   25/2/2016
E   28/2/2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first get the month for each record and then sort.  With that you can pull the observations out with a data step as follows:

```
data test.doc1;                                                                                                                         
set test.doc;                                                                                                                           

Month = month(__Vis_date);                                                                                                              
run;                                                                                                                                    

proc sort data=test.doc1;                                                                                                               
by Cust_name Month __Vis_date;                                                                                                          
run;                                                                                                                                    

data test.doc2;                                                                                                                         
set test.doc1;                                                                                                                          
by Cust_name Month;                                                                                                                     
if first.Month then output;                                                                                                             
run;
```

Comment: This will only work for one year's worth of data, if you have more than one year within your data, you will get incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable that keeps track of the month, this becomes pretty easy! Vis_date needs to be formatted as a date variable for this to work though.

```
data your_data2;
    set your_data;
    month = month(vis_date);
run;

proc sort data = your_data2;
by cust_name vis_date;
run;

proc sort nodupkey data = your_data2;
by cust_name month;
run;
```

Comment: this doesn't pull out the first record of each month for each customer

Comment: Sort by cust_name vis_date first and then nodupkey it by cust_name month - my bad.

Comment: Using of your codes, i have done some changes and got the answer. Thanks for you support friends. The changed code is below,              

data your_data2;
    set your_data;
    month = month(vis_date);
 check = catx("_",Cust_name,month);
 run;

proc print;
 run;

proc sort data = Your_data2 nodupkey; 
by Vis_date;
by check; 
run;

proc print data = Your_data2;
run;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single SQL statement :

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select Cust_name, 
         put(Vis_date,yymmn6.) as Month, 
         min(Vis_Date) as First_Date format=date9.
  from have 
  group by 1,2
  order by 1,2 ;
quit ;
```